# Where are the hahne-kedar arms in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I played through the entire game and was unable to find them, I checked after every mission I did. The only thing I can assume is that it may require the Hanar Diplomat mission, as that is the only one I didn't do (not my choice.. the bug happened to me). Where are them?

I'd also like to add that I thought it made sense that this mission needed to be completed because I have read that the guide says you buy them at the hanar store.

Answer (score 3):

You can buy the Hahne-Kedar arms in the [Kanala Exports store](http://www.ign.com/wikis/mass-effect-3/Kanala_Exports).  From [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/995452-/62228506):

> The gauntlets are located in the Kanala Exports. When you first clear out a shop of its inventory and you complete a Priority mission[,] its inventory is re-stocked with new items. You should be able to get the gauntlets as you clear out the Kanala Exports shop.

And from [the ME wikia](http://masseffect.answers.wikia.com/wiki/Where_is_the_Hahne-Kedar_arms):

> From my experience, they become available after the mission on Menae, at the Normandy's terminal in the shuttle bay. The last two times I did this, I went to the Citadel after this mission, bought everything there was to buy at Kanala Exports kiosk. Then aboard the Normandy, at the terminal in the shuttle bay, Kanala Exports stock is refreshed, and HK arms are available.

I'm only seeing [one other claim about this](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/995487-mass-effect-3/62244929?page=1):

> You can get them after Palaven at the Hanar Store in the Citadel.

Comment: That's not how stores work in ME3.

Comment: Do you have any confirmation of this besides a random post on GameFAQs?

Comment: @bwarner [The ME wikia confirms](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Armor_Customization_(Mass_Effect_3)#Arms), though it does say "imports" not "exports".  I've added another bit to the answer from a different part of the wiki as well, plus the only contradicting info I was able to find.

Comment: @kotekzot How do they work? If you've done this and it doesn't work, please let me know and I'll remove my answer.

Comment: Items become available in shops after you have missed them in the mission where they were available. It has nothing to do with clearing out a shop's inventory.

Comment: @kotekzot I see. Assuming this isn't an exception, I wonder if no one seems to have found them during a mission due to a bug. Either that or my searching sucks / no one posted about it.

Comment: In support of your answer, the wiki suggests that these are only available through store purchase (but doesn't say when): http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Armor_Customization_%28Mass_Effect_3%29#Arms